# Macroeconomic Measures of Human Capital

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, solow

How exactly do you measure human capital for a given country and what numbers are included in that measure.

The reason why I ask is because im interested in simulating the [Mankiw–Romer–Weil version of the solow Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solow%E2%80%93Swan_model#Addition_of_human_capital).

Links to where I can get the data will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The approach developed by [Barro and Lee](http://barrolee.com/Lee_Lee_LRdata.htm) has been used in many empirical analysis. They provide a detailed discussion of how to construct an aggregate human capital measure.